# Filing FBAR if I wire transfer to my parents Account?

Tags: india, non-resident, wire-transfer, fbar

Do I need to file FBAR if I send $25000 to my fathers account in India?

Answer (score 1):

Do you have signature authority or interest in the account? Then yes.

Interest in the account means that you wire $25K to your dad, but the money still belongs to you (I.e.: if you ask for it your dad will give it back to you).

Comment: How can interest in account be officially proved ?

Comment: @JavaDeveloper you never know who might agree to testify against you.

Comment: @JavaDeveloper You have an interest in the account if you are listed as a co-owner of the account along with your parents. This is a very common practice in India. Signature authority means that you can operate the account too, withdrawing money from it, or transferring it elsewhere. In India, it is common practice that a bank will allow only the first-named account holder to operate the account, but legally, you have an interest in the account as well as signature authority even though the bank will fight tooth-and-nail against allowing the latter.